# Doctrine Annotations Exception - Strange Error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

When i try to generate entities or update the schema;

[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@index" in class Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Translation was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

What is the problem?

I have tried;

- Clearing cache,
- Clearing doctrine cache,
- Chmod,
- Chown,
- Composer Update

More information:

I'm not using gedmo translations now. It's installed but not used!

I don't have any use of translation annotations.

This happened after updating symfony2.4 to 2.6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It's a bug

Unfortunately the class doc-block of `Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\Translation` contains the annotation `@index` (in stead of `@Index`, with a capital "I"). This can cause issues on case-sensitive filesystems.

This has been fixed in commit [1926773: Removed unused use statements and added a missing one](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/commit/1926773937a1178d4c9849bb34868ec7050b8354), but that hasn't been tagged/released yet.

Because you upgraded Symfony, you probably also upgraded Doctrine. I'm not sure in which version of Doctrine this happened, but in the past missing annotations were simply ignored. Nowadays an exception is thrown. This is probably why you're having this issue after an upgrade.

#### Disable missing annotation exceptions

One solution is to ignore the `@index` (lowercase "i") annotations:

```
AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('index');
```

Documentation: [2.2.3. Ignoring missing exceptions](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/latest/annotations.html#ignoring-missing-exceptions)

Or completely disable the import validation mechanism:

```
$reader = new \Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader();
$reader->setEnabledPhpImports(false);
```

Documentation: [2.2.4. PHP Imports](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/latest/annotations.html#php-imports)

Note that this last feature will be removed in future versions of Doctrine.

#### Disable Translatable mappings

Even though you're not using the Translatable extension, you probably have its mappings enabled.
Otherwise the class wouldn't be loaded and the error wouldn't occur.

Search for something like this in your `app/config/config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    entity_managers:
      default:
        mappings:
          gedmo_translatable:
            type: annotation
            prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
            dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
            alias: GedmoTranslatable
            is_bundle: false
          gedmo_translator:
            type: annotation
            prefix: Gedmo\Translator\Entity
            dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translator/Entity"
            alias: GedmoTranslator
            is_bundle: false
```

You should *only* include the mappings of the extensions you're actually using.

#### Upgrade gedmo/doctrine-extensions

Change the requirement of `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` in your `composer.json` to at least 1926773. You could also ask the maintainer to release a new version that includes the bug-fix.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Index;` at the top of your Translation entity.